# JavaScript function with jquery in it not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Been playing around with Javascript and Jquery. Everything was working fine until I added a function. There aren't any error messages. I click the button and nothing happens.

```
function offOn() {
    var ballCount = 1;
    var ballsCount = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        $("<div class='grid-inner' id='" + i + "'></div>").appendTo(".grid");

        if (i == 45 || i == 100 || i == 82) {
            $("<div class='ball' id='ball" + ballCount + "'></div>" + "<div class='arrow-down' id='arrow'></div>" + "<p class='ex'><b>" + ballsCount + "</b></p>").appendTo("#" + i + "");
            ballCount++;
            ballsCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the HTML

```
<button class="click" onclick="offOn()">START</button>
```

Comment: can you explain more clearly

Comment: there is your code: http://jsfiddle.net/sherali/gcz4gwgw/2/  . what problem

Comment: Start debugging; don't make us do it. You have a debugger, debug. You have console.log, log. (And what's the point of adding on an empty string to something that's already a string? `"#" + i + ""`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like keeping **structure** & **behavior** separate so that debugging is easier to do. I switched things up and it seems to work for me.

Remove `onclick=onOff()` from your HTML to separate markup from behavior

HTML

```
<button class="click" id="btn">START</button>
<div class="grid"></div>
```

Add that behavior using jQuery by giving it a `click` handler to take charge when the button is pressed. This makes things more cleaner by only having to look at your jQuery to see if it's a fault in your logic rather than the possibility of misspelled function name or issues with your markup.

jQuery

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
  var ballCount = 1;
  var ballsCount = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    $("<div class='grid-inner' id='" + i + "'></div>").appendTo(".grid");

    if (i == 45 || i == 100 || i == 82) {
      $("<div class='ball' id='ball" + ballCount + "'></div>" + "<div class='arrow-down' id='arrow'></div>" + "<p class='ex'><b>" + ballsCount + "</b></p>").appendTo("#" + i + "");
        ballCount++;
        ballsCount++;
    }
  } 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7tox109h/

Comment: What did you fix/change? What was the problem? Answers with zero explanation are never as good as answers with a good explanation.

Comment: sorry, this is the first time i use this website. I had no idea how and what to put. But thanks. This helped.

Comment: Were you able to get it to work through this example @Dan ?

Answer (score -1):

http://jsfiddle.net/hzqma690/

this works for me, I wrote sss just to see the div rendered:

```
function offOn() {
    var ballCount = 1;
    var ballsCount = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        $(".grid").append("<div class='grid-inner' id='" + i + "'>sss</div>");

        if (i == 45 || i == 100 || i == 82) {
            $('#'+i).append("<div class='ball' id='ball" + ballCount + "'></div>" + "<div class='arrow-down' id='arrow'></div>" + "<p class='ex'><b>" + ballsCount + "</b></p>")
            ballCount++;
            ballsCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I changed the question code using append instead that appendTo.

Comment: What did you fix/change?  What was the problem?  Answers with zero explanation are never as good as answers with a good explanation.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/k6x9yuuk/8/

for some reason it just doesn't work on here.
as soon as I take the function off it works fine.

Comment: @jfriend00: just do some compare, it's on the .append() functions. you used newdom.appendTo(oldDom), I prefer oldDom.append(newdom)

Comment: Check on the left side of the jsfildde, in the menu bar "Frameworks & Extensions" -> your script must be NOT onload, but in HEAD. check the second select box, after you choose the jquery plugin

Comment: You don't seem to understand about good answers here on StackOverflow.  Good answers explain themselves.  They don't require someone to do their own visual diff to try to figure out what the answer is showing.  You can use the "edit" link to add a description of what the problem was and what you changed.